# Filtering MYSQL pull using datetimefield model django

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I have been having a hard time finding a solution specific to filtering a model get from a mysql db.

models file:

```
class PreviousLossesMlbV5WithDateAgg(models.Model):
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    date_field = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'previous_losses_mlb_v5_with_date_agg'
```

views file

```
def indexsss(request):
    monday_new = PreviousLossesMlbV5WithDateAgg.objects.values_list('game_points_with_formula_field',flat=True).filter(date_field= '2021-07-05')
    monday_list = list(monday_new)
    
    return render(request, "show4.html", context={'test45': monday_list}
                  )
```

The data does not populate and also shows this in the terminal

```
DateTimeField PreviousLossesMlbV5WithDateAgg.date_field received a naive datetime (2021-07-05 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this, I was having issues due to specifying a timezone in the settings page. For my application I am only pulling dates saved in databases so I really do not need Django to adjust timezones or anything like that. I commented out

```
#TIME_ZONE = 'US/Mountain'

#USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
PreviousLossesMlbV5WithDateAgg.objects.filter(date_field__date= datetime.date(2021,07,05)).values_list('game_points_with_formula_field',flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, been really busy lately. just gave it a go and still not returning any data, I do have "00:00:00" in my time zone column.